# Replace old values in new values from an Excel Table en masse

Tags: excel, replace, excel-formula

I have a large table with about 1,500 values. And I need to replace the "old" values with the "new" values in the table. Basically, I need to "find and replace" en masse.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Red | Cherry |
| Blue | Indigo |

If we were take the example above. Say I have a column that has a list of all of our products. Red car, blue mouse, etc. What I need to do is say "Look in column C (containing the products) for the value in column A and Replace it with the value in column B".

So, for example. Let's say I have "Red Car" I would want it to now say "Cherry Car". This is a simplistic way of putting it, but there are around 1,500 values and they are all just numbers. So it's not as simple as doing a find and replace unless I want to spend days finding and replacing and hoping I did it all right.

Here's an example of what it really looks like:

| Old Value | New Value |
| --- | --- |
| 653111 | 21870538 |
| 694182 | 21212412 |
| 653141 | 34123451 |

| Table of Products |
| --- |
| 653111xyr |
| 694182jfh |
| 653141ren |

Comment: vlookup then copy and paste to overwrite the values.

Comment: Probably better to do this programmatically, e.g. using VBA.

Comment: How many old/new value pairs do you have? Where are they located?

Comment: 1,100 products. 1,500 old values and 1,500 new values. Old value in column A. New value in column B. List of products in column A on another tab. All in excel.

Comment: Are the values you want to replace always at the beginning of the product? Also, are the old values all the same length?

Comment: If the values to replace are always at the beginning of the product, and the values to replace are always the same length; then you could write a formula that extracts the value to be replaced, and uses `VLOOKUP` to get the new value; if there is a new value, concatenate that with the rest. If you would be willing to use VBA, this logic might be better expressed in a function; alternatively, some code to iterate over all the products and fix them.

Comment: Yes the values are always at the beginning but there can be multiple. For example here is what a few samples of the column look like:

(1391928RWS OR 14241402VSJ) 
(1473110GTS OR 3646579JFS OR 1473111LLK) 
(1391925TRE OR 1391927TRE) 
650685LLK
12869079MYT 
1473111LLK 
(12838773TRT OR 12891730TRT) 
17788516SYL

And so I have a table that says: (Column A) 17788516  (Column B New Value To Replace): 54212351

So essentially I would need to look for every instance of 17788516 and replace it with 54212351. The following letters can remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using VBA (or if something similar can be done using Office.js) to iterate over each of the old/new value pairs, and programmatically do a global Find/Replace on the products sheet.

Using VBA:

```vba
Dim mappings() As Variant
mappings = Worksheets("Mappings").UsedRange.Value

Dim row As Integer, rowCount As Integer
rowCount = UBound(mappings, 1)
For row = 1 To rowCount
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Products")
    wks.UsedRange.Replace mappings(row, 1), mappings(row, 2), xlPart
Next
```

Given the number of products and mappings you have, I think this likely will take some time to run.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you:
`=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1,6)),Sheet2!A:A,0))&RIGHT(A1,3)`
Sheet2 in this case contains the old and new value data.
A1 is the current value you want to have changed.
This is provided all the data has same length of numbers and characters.